# Getting TextView view object from "onCreate" Activity's method

Tags: android

I'm having trouble on trying to retrieve a ***TextView*** object by its id inside my ***onCreate*** method from an Activity.

My activity's xml Fragment TextView's section:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/message_display_field"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

The ***onCreate*** method:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    // Create the text view
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message_display_field);
    tv.setText(message);
}
```

`TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message_display_field);` do not return the textView I expect it to return but null instead

Finally as one would expect, this throws a `NullPointerException`.

Then how could I retrieve my TextView *view* object if this is not the way to go ? `:(`

Notes :

- There are no warnning or error before I press the Run button to launch the application through the emulator.
- NullPointer is fired at runtime.

I will appriciate any help, thank you in advance !

Comment: Is the `TextView` within your `activity_display_message` XML file?

Comment: Is ur textView inside fragment?

Comment: @NoXSaeeD @user184994 Yes it is `:/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually if your TextView inside Fragment xml what u have to do is :

1- go to class fragment override onCreateView method from there you get all view inside fragment like so.

```
TextView foo;as //globle var

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);

    foo = rootView.findViewById(R.id.message_display_field);

    return rootView;                 
}
```

now you are happy
i hope this helps

Comment: well that's actually wrong. onCreate is called before onCreateView. You probably meant to write onActivityCreate or better onViewCreated, don't you?

Comment: yes you right i meant onCreateView so here's how you get view from fragment

Comment: answer edited done, if i'm going to get best answer coz there no one else me who answered with vote will be nice thanks.